# How often is the incident API updated with new events?

Tags: here-api

How frequently is the incident API updated with new events? In particular for Germany?

For our use case we are only really interested in newsworthy incidents such as traffic accidents and need to report them as soon as possible after the actual event.

Answer (score 0):

The Traffic APIs are based on the Incident and flow feed.

> **Incident**: every 2 min
>   **Flow**: every min

You can also refer our documentation to more about the API
https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/example-incidents-intro.html